# "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function" Error in console log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've a form where a field called "**keyword**" exist. When I click on this field it's showing me a **popup box** where all `keywords` are showing form Mysql database.

So When I first load the full index.php page it's workiing fine. But after requesting sever jquery/ajax request for other purpose it's not popup the **keyword box**. In console log I see following error message :

Can someone tell me why it's showing this error message ?

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
$("#dialog_keywords").dialog('open').load("getKeywords.php");
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script>
    var $ad_keywords;
    var $totalkeywords = 0;
    $( "#dialog_keywords" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 1160,
        height: 450,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    var selected_keywords = new Array("");
                    var z = 0;
                    for(xxrow = 0; xxrow < $totalkeywords; xxrow++)
                    {
                        if($('#keyword_'+xxrow).hasClass("keywordHighlight2")){
                            selected_keywords[z] = $('#keyword_'+xxrow).html();
                            z++;
                        }
                    }
                    selected_keywords.sort()
                    $("#ad_keyword").val(selected_keywords);

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            {
                text: "Cancel",
                click: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    var keywordinit = 0;
    $( "#ad_keyword" ).click(function( event ) {
        $ad_keywords = $("#ad_keyword").val().split(',');
        if(keywordinit == 0){
            keywordinit = 1;
            $('#dialog_keywords').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $("#dialog_keywords").dialog('open').load("getKeywords.php");
        }
        else{
            $("#dialog_keywords").dialog('open');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

**Update:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="include/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Do you load `dialog` library first?

Comment: @Justinas check my update questions what I'm using on html `head` section.

Comment: It's a better practice to add the CSS before the scripts.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you get the **error** at later point of time. If `dialog()` is not defined then it'll not work for the first time. Are you loading any conflicting files through the requests..? Can you share the code for *other purpose*..?